# copy() when using data.table inside functions

Tags: r, data.table

On my projects I usually do the data prepping with a few functions, so my code usually look like this:

```
readAndClean("directory") %>% 
  processing() %>% 
  readyForModelling()
```

Where I'm passing a data.table object from one function to another.

I've gotten a habit to always start this functions with:

```
processing <- function(data_init){
  data <- copy(data_init)
}
```

to avoid making changes to the DT on the global environment, as the following example will:

```
test <- data.table(cars[1:10,])

processing <- function(data_init){
  data_init[, id := 1:.N]
  
  return("done")
}

test
#    speed dist
# 1:     4    2
# 2:     4   10
# 3:     7    4
# 4:     7   22
# 5:     8   16
# 6:     9   10
# 7:    10   18
# 8:    10   26
# 9:    10   34
# 10:    11   17
processing(test)
# [1] "done"

test
#    speed dist id
# 1:     4    2  1
# 2:     4   10  2
# 3:     7    4  3
# 4:     7   22  4
# 5:     8   16  5
# 6:     9   10  6
# 7:    10   18  7
# 8:    10   26  8
# 9:    10   34  9
# 10:    11   17 10
```

But this always seems a little ugly to me.
Is it the correct way of handling data.tables inside functions?

Comment: Using `copy` kind of defeats the purpose of data.table because you'll lose most of its efficiency.

Comment: @Roland even if it's just once on the beggining of the code? After it I'm doing several aggregations, joins and variable creations with the copied table.

Comment: Then you might still have some benefit but a deep copy is very expensive in terms of performance. It won't matter much if your data is rather small and you use data.table primarily for its nice syntax. What I don't get is why you want to avoid changing the original data.table in your specific case. I'd think that modifying in place would be quite convenient if you are doing "data prepping".

Comment: I guess if you have multiple parallel `processing()` steps working on the same raw data you would want to leave the raw data as is, or if you were testing and wanted to compare the before and after processing. But if it's a large dataset I'd try to make the most of modifiying in place and not make duplicates of my data. Still useful, conceptually, to arrange things like you do though.